# Word for a Person Skilled in Handicraft

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-politics

I'm looking for a term to describe a person who is skilled in handicraft. Specifically, I have a friend who leaves me amazed with every drawing, painting, fimo figure, friendship bracelet, sculpture, model of the Millennium Falcon in a bottle or anything else conjured by her own fingers, and I'm looking for a term to describe this aspect of her.
I don't really like "craftswoman". The closest I got is "artisan", but I'm looking for more options to see if there's something that fits better.

Comment: Oh no, here we go again. A gender-neutral term for [craftsperson](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205282/gender-neutral-alternative-to-craftsmanship)! :)

Comment: 'Handicraft' is biased against those who use their feet!

Comment: It should be 'Limbsicraftperdaughter'

Comment: It's not quite a good enough fit for an answer to the whole question, but *artist* springs to mind -- though this may suggest a certain mindset as well.

Comment: Those concerned with gender specific terms should first use *hertory* instead *history* and then get themselves checked :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Handicraftsman*** (as specific as it gets)

> A worker skilled in making objects by hand [[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/handicraftsman)

---

**Note:** If one is too concerned with gender specific terms, there is *handicraftswoman* also. But *handicraftsman* is used for both genders.

There is also *handicrafter* if you do not want to mention man or woman.

Comment: Handicraft: A craft or occupation requiring _skilled_ use of the hands. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/handicraft)

Comment: What, *handicrafter* exists? Really? So why is there no *handicraftsperson* then as well? ;)

Comment: @syntaxerror Because we already have handicraftsman? And that's shorter?

Comment: But handicrafts*man* refers to men only. And hence, the gender-neutral variant---apart from the aforementioned *handicrafter*---might as well be *handicraftsperson*.

Comment: @syntaxerror: _Handicraftsman_ is used for both genders. _Handicraftsperson_ is not a well-recognized word and it is very uncommon.

Comment: Sure thing, I am aware of that. But maybe it should be made more popular, since in my book, using *handicraftsman* for a woman must feel pretty odd due to its "manly suffix". But OTOH, I'd like "female handicrafter" a lot (whereas "handicraftswoman" sounds as if recently coined by feminists ;)) -- Whee. Most complicated stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As an extra thought - is there a word that implies less of a "worker" skilled in handicraft, and more of an "artist" skilled in handicraft?

Comment: @ShayHacohen: Then, you can use "artisan" as you already mentioned.

Comment: @ermanen - Okay, thanks again! Those seem to be the most fitting words, so I'll alternate between "artisan" and the terms you suggested, depending on the context.

Comment: @ShayHacohen: Artisan is used for someone who has a "worker" skill too. These words are associated with professions because these people craft things and usually sell them. Throughout the history, this sense was stronger but nowadays people do it for fun too. If you want to completely move away from "worker" skill then it is better to use phrases. For example: "He is good with his hands." or "She has skilled hands." etc.

Comment: @ShayHacohen: You can have an idea about how common associated words are in Google Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=handicraftsman%2Chandicrafter%2Chandicraftswoman%2Chandicraftsperson%2Ccraftswoman%2Ccraftsman%2Ccrafter%2Cartisan&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chandicraftsman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chandicrafter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccraftswoman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccraftsman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrafter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cartisan%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ermanen - the reason I asked this question is that everything felt a little too much on the "worker" side to me, so this makes perfect sense! I like the idea of using a phrase here. :) And thanks for the graph!

Answer (score 9):

A [**crafter**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/crafter)-n.- a creator of great skill in the manual arts

[image]

A [**traditionalist**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/traditionalist) -n.-describes a person who believes *old school* ways are best. e.g.favors writing letters over sending emails.

Comment: *crafter* is a surprisingly controversial word. It often has the connotation of bored women with gluesticks.

Comment: I know lots of *crafters*, @dnagirl, and none of them are bored women with gluesticks.  (Ok, maybe a couple might qualify, but better to use gluesticks than popsicle sticks, I say!) Still, I'd have no problems calling someone who creates fabric art like quilts, a *crafter* and don't think they'd object to the title. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Some don't. Some do. As I said, it's a controversial term. The issue boils down to the difference between *art* and *craft* and it's the reason that many makers choose to call themselves *artisans* and will object strenuously to being called *crafter*.

Answer (score 3):

Artisan (by definition skilled)

Comment: The OP himself/herself used the word *artisan* and said he was looking for more options.

Answer (score -1):

Handicraft is also known as artisanry.  As such, your friend could either be an artisan or, more simply, a handicrafter (as used in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicraft)).

> [handicrafter (Merriam Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/handicrafter) 
>   a person whose occupation requires skill with the hands

or

> [artisan (Merriam Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artisan)
>   a person who is skilled at making things by hand

There's also, [crafter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/crafter) or [craftsman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/craftsman).

Comment: There ya go... downvote with no comment.  good plan.

Comment: The down-voter was not I, but perhaps it was because the OP himself/herself used the word artisan and said he was looking for *more options*. Additionally you used ermanen's handicrafter, and Mysti's *crafter*. Perhaps you will consider my comment in lieu of your downvoter's.

Comment: I was the first with handicrafter, with definition and usage link.  I didn't "use ermanen's handicrafter", rather he pulled from my answer (check the edit history).  Also, I'm providing a canonical answer with all the options that I see valid.  Still, thank you for explaining the anonymous downvote

Comment: I don't know if you know this, but we can see the times on all postings, including comments and edits. @Ermanen's edit was done at 18:44:24Z while your *first answer* was at 19:18:10Z - more than 30 minutes later. If you're going to make accusations, make sure you can back them up. Finally, no one would have called you out if you hadn't complained about the downvote.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that. I didn't notice that his answer originally included handicrafter when I posted mine, though. My mistake for being human I guess. Feel free to down vote into oblivion. I stand by this as well the most accurate answer, though, as I don't believe in the word handicraftsman. But hey, we all have opinions and we can all rant, can't we?

Answer (score -1):

How about just plain ole' TALENTED.

Comment: You can be talented in many many different fields. A more accurate word might have been *skilled*, but that's already in the title. Your suggestion would have been appropriate as a comment, it does not really answer the OP's question, as a result this post risks deletion. You can edit and expand on your answer, if you disagree that your suggestion is too generic.