# What is a gender-neutral or inclusive term for "craftsmen"?

Tags: grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

I understand *craftsmen* may not technically be considered a gendered term, however, it has '-men' in it. So, I would rather use something else that doesn't exclude those who are maybe unfamiliar with the robust origins and technicalities of gender in language.

I am specifically looking for a (generic) noun that can be used for a person or group of people. Replacing '-men' with '-person' is not ideal since it usually sounds strange for most words, especially in this case.

Similar post, but not helpful: [Gender-neutral alternative to "craftsmanship"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205282/gender-neutral-alternative-to-craftsmanship)